# Showing that there is a unique solution for the following equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $I = (0, 1)$, $a : H_0^2(I) \times H_0^2(I) \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous bilinear form defined by 
$$a(u, v) = \int\limits_I u'' (x) v'' (x) dx.$$

Show that for every $f \in L^2(I)$ there is a unique solution $u \in H_0^2(I)$ of the equation 
$$\int\limits_I u''(x) v''(x) dx = \int\limits_I f(x) v(x) dx, 
\;\; \forall v \in H_0^2(I).$$

Can someone, please, give me a hint?

Thank you!

P.S: We can introduce an operator $(A, D(A))$, where $D(A) = H^4(I) \cap H_0^2(I)$ and $A u = u_{xxxx}$. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that the bilinear form is coercive in $H^2$. To do so, you have to use the inequality
$$
\|u\|_{H^1} \le c \|u''\|_{L^2} \quad \forall u\in H^2_0(\Omega).
$$
Then by Lax-Milgram theorem you obtain existence of a unique solution for all $f$.

Comment: I showed. How does it help me?

Comment: See edit: Lax-Milgram theorem